# How to detect a control in a windows form and edit it c#

Tags: c#, winforms, testing, controls, read-write

[image]
My form

So, i have this Form with a TableLayoutPanel witch contains text boxes.
I need the code to check if there is a textbox on my form and it is empty -  then write text in it
else {keep looking for an existing, empty text box} 
The order doesn't matter

Comment: Did you try to write a loop over the Controls collection of your TableLayoutPanel?

Comment: `tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<RichTextBox>() .Where(x=>string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Text)).ToList().ForEach(x=>x.Text = "something");`

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Control contr in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
        {
            if (contr is RichTextBox)
            {
                if ((contr as RichTextBox).Text == string.Empty)
                {
                    contr.Text = str_product;
                }
            }

        }
```